# Ubuntu 18.04 Dell 2408WFP monitor low resolution

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with NVidia Geforce GTX 460 graphics card and set up dual monitor with an HP and Dell monitor. My HP monitor is fine and can display a maximum of 1920x1200 resolution, but my Dell 2408WFP monitor is not recognized and I can only set a max resolution of 1600x900. When I run windows on the same setup both monitors display the max res of 1920x1200. But when I boot Ubuntu I can't get the Dell monitor to display at the max resolution.

when I run `xrandr --listactivemonitors`, I get:

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +*DVI-I-2 1920/546x1200/352+0+0  DVI-I-2
 1: +DVI-I-3 1600/423x900/238+1920+0  DVI-I-3
```

I used the command `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install NVidia drivers. When I run the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` I get the following:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:0a:00.0/0000:0b:00.0/0000:0d:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000E22sv0000196Esd00000865bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF104 [GeForce GTX 460]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I tried changing the resolution using NVidia X Server Settings application, but I can't.
At this point I don't know what else I can do so that my Dell monitor is recognized and set the max resolution of 1920x1200. Any thoughts? Thank you!

**Edit 1**
Just to help clarify, the Dell monitor is currently connected to a DVI port on the GTX 460 card. I also tried connecting the Dell monitor to the HDMI port on the card and I still can't go higher than 1600x900 and the Dell monitor still not recognized. In the NVIDIA Settings window, the Dell monitor comes up as DFP-2, while the second HP monitors comes up under the model number.

**Edit 2**
So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04. After installation completed and I logged in my Dell monitor is working perfectly fine at 1920x1200 resolution and it's recognized as I can see the model in the Display settings window. I decided to install the NVidia drivers using the command above and after I rebooted the Dell monitor was no longer recognized and it changed the resolution back to 1600x900. I attempted to revert back using **Software Settings** and clicking the **Additional Drivers** tab. I proceeded to click on the X.org Nouveau open source drivers and both monitors were no longer working at their maximum resolution. So it seems that it might be an issue with NVidia drivers... I don't know. I would like to know if its possible to fix the problem while using the NVidia drivers, otherwise I'm gonna have to stick with the open source drivers.

Comment: That happens sometimes with VGA. Prefer HDMI or DVI, problem solved. Otherwise it'll be sorta of a PITA to create a new mode with xrandr.

Comment: Unfortunately my problem is with DVI as well as HDMI. I have plugged the Dell monitor on either port and I'm still having issues with the resolution and not being recognized.

Comment: It can't be. With DVI I may think about a thing that can go wrong (wrong type of cable) but not with HDMI and graphics drivers installed. **That would be a first!** And why are you still using VGA?

Comment: I've never said I'm using VGA. On my post if you look at the lines where I posted the results from running 'xrandr --listactivemonitors' you'll see that the connections are DVI for both monitors.

Comment: I was just messing with you ;) Does the DVI cable have all the pins? The Dell monitor wants a fully DVI-D compatible cable. To avoid confusion just use HDMI, even a DVI (PC) to HDMI (monitor) cable/adapter may give better results.

Comment: The cable I have is DVI to HDMI and it does have all of the pins. Like I said, I tried using the HDMI port as well and I can't change the resolution more than 1600x900. On Windows this is not a problem and the Dell monitor is set to 1920x1200. I'm not sure if the problem has to do with the fact that Ubuntu can't recognized the Dell monitor and its using some default settings for that purpose.

Comment: Again, you're the first reporting such weirdness. I have no suggestions except using xrandr.

Comment: So it seems :(
I tried `xrandr -s 1920x1200` and it ends up disabling the Dell monitor completely. I have to use NVidia settings to enable it again.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia changing from VGA to DVI worked for me.